Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 ()
I run a website where I publish manga using WordPress. There is a WordPress plugin MADARA-CORE for uploading manhwa and manga, but the issue is that I cannot upload files larger than 20 MB and sometimes even 60MB.
I don't really understand what causes the failing, even though the server should be capable of handling even larger files. Sometimes the upload works, but other times it doesn't. I have tried all versions of PHP but continue to face the same problem.
Currently, I am using the latest PHP version and have increased the PHP settings configurations, including file upload limits and other configurations to facilitate the process, but to no avail. What is the solution?
I tried different and max values for all of these:
php_value upload_max_filesize
php_value post_max_size
php_value memory_limit
php_value max_execution_time
php_value max_input_time

The error message i always get in the console of browser is like that

"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503
()"

I've also tried the same template on my friends host server and I faced nothing like this error. Can you guide me?
This is my server information:

Server Name: server1428
Server Location: Europe (France) (which is close to my users)|
Disk Space: 100 GB
RAM: 1024 MB
CPU Cores: 1
Inodes: 400000
Addons/Websites: 100
Active Processes: 40
Entry Processes: 20
Bandwidth: Unlimited



Disk Usage is 4% out of 100GB and Files And Directories (inodes) Limit 19 130 Used out of 400 000.
WordPress Environment
Home URL: https://mangatuk.com/
Site URL: https://mangatuk.com/
WP Version: 6.6.1
WP Multisite: _
WP Memory Limit: 64 MB
WP Debug Mode: _
Language: ar
Server Environment
Server Environment
PHP Version: 8.3.6

PHP Post Max Size:   128 MB
PHP Time Limit:   300


PHP Max Input Vars: 5000
SUHOSIN Installed: –
ZipArchive: Available
MySQL Version: 10.11.8

Max Upload Size:  128 MB


DOMDocument: Available
WP Remote Get: Available
WP Remote Post: Available
GD Library: 2.3.3

So as you can see it's pretty weird to get error while uploading 60mb using MADARA MANGA PLUGIN! It's not too large. What could be the issue?
Just another thing to mention I'm using Amazon s3 Bucket to host my files using Amazon API.

UPDATE: looks like the problem was resulting for 3 reasons:

Missing AmazonS3 Bucket permission policies.
So far Bucket region from my location.
Limited hostinger resources - don't exactly what is the limit but Seems like sometimes Throughput (I/O) is going so high on Resources
Usage Graph (because of big file size) and also for some reason i can
only upload a zip that contains 588 files, 95.3 MB.

Here is a list for my upload tests :

242 files, 111 MB -> done
277 files, 94.3 MB -> done
303 files, 89.2 MB -> done
385 files, 137 MB -> done
515 files, 93.5 MB -> done
555 files, 109 MB -> done
576 files, 100 MB -> done
583 files, 112 MB -> done
586 files, 109 MB -> failed
588 files, 95.3 MB -> done
589 files, 105 MB -> failed
590 files, 108 MB -> failed
613 files, 112 MB -> failed
666 files, 130 MB -> failed

even tho it's still strange for 586 files, 109 MB -> failed and for
588 files, 95.3 MB -> done.


I've made an attempt to clean up the formatting and removed some of the begging language as well as the solicitation to pay-to-fix as that is inappropriate for this site (there are other sites online where you can pick up a developer for pay to work through issues like this, but not stackoverflow). Apologies, OP, if I removed anything important. Your original edit is still available in the edit history if something should need to be restored.

As for your question, when changing your php settings, did you restart your server? Also what does your php logs say? They likely have more information then just the generic 503 that the web page spits out.

Firstly i'm sorry for being that bad at writing and thank you for taking your time to format the post i really appericiate it sir.
about the issue i don't really know what is wrong it's just random! sometimes i can upload 60MB and sometimes i get the same server error for only 20MB it's really annoting and taking a lot of time for my team to just work on one Manga Volume.
we are ready to take any action just to go forward and keep working without stupid issues like these!!!
and NO i don't know if it's possible to restart the server on Shared Servers?
but i checked the settings are applied

"about the issue i don't really know what is wrong" - that's why you should go and check the error log! The mere status code you are getting when looking at this from the client side, is not supposed to give away too much information about the cause of such errors. WP Debug Mode: _ - so you mean you have not even enabled debug mode yet?

i already enabled the debug mode not one time not two but for days but still it doesn't log the 503 error for some reason also tried different plugins but again same!

i talked to the support team of hostinger they tried to log the issue and they told me that the issue is related to limited resources they asked me to disable plugins and stuff but it didn't help at last they told me that the problem is the timeout which is fixed to 6minute.. but my upload fails after 2 minute of start point. so it's not the timeout neither.
